# Should I standardize forecasted and actual values for Mincer Zarnowitz test?

Tags: time-series, garch, standardization, volatility-forecasting, out-of-sample

I have some out-of-sample forecasted values of variance through some GARCH model, and now I am trying to perform a Mincer-Zarnowitz test for validity of my predictions. I first standardized both actual and forecasted values and ran the regression, then repeated with the raw data afterwards and R^2 was the same, although coefficients were different.

I have looked around but couldn't see anything about standardization for MZ test. Any help would be highly appreciated.